# Intuition for Lie Group Representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm currently learning about Lie Group representations and I have two questions about them.

1. What is the inuitive difference between group *actions* and *representations*? Is the only real difference that in the former case, a group acts on a manifold, and the latter case, it acts on a vector space? And why are we so intensely focused on groups acting on *vector spaces* in particular?
2. What are intuitive, geometric examples of representations? For example, elements of the rotation group $\text{SO}(2)$ act on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by rotating it. Elements of $\text{SO}(3)$ act on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by rotating it. But we already studied both of these examples without developing the whole theory of representations. Are there any examples of representations that one can *visualize* (for example, not the adjoint representation) that are not trivial like the examples above?

Any clarification about these questions would be much appreciated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. Groups *act* on a set, and representations "represent" groups by matrices. That's a big difference in general. Groups may act on various things, not just vector spaces (see groups acting on trees etc.). 2. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group) for examples with $SO(2),SO(3)$ etc.

Comment: We are focused on vector spaces because *linear algebra is easy*. That's a slogan which is not always true, but as a general rule of thumb, if you manage to somehow convert a difficult problem into linear algebraic terms, then you're on the right track to solving it. Perhaps a better word than "easy" would be "well understood".

Comment: Group actions *other than* representations are normally called "realizations" and are ubiquitous in physics. Kronecker multiplying matrices into large matrices, however, systematizes the representation theory of a group with large matrices nicely.